# ! Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again> \MessageBreak

Tags: errors, sv-classes

Hi I'm working on a LaTeX project and I get some errors. One of them is

> Missing \endcsname inserted.  \MessageBreak

This is my code

```
\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,braket}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{nccrules}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum,booktabs}

\usepackage{todonotes}

%%table footnote
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakcites} %%break citation
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{subcaption} %%for subcaption command
\usepackage{tabularx}


\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.1,0.1,0.1}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{relsize}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}


 \title{  \textbf{ Mining Time-constrained Sequential
Patterns with Constraint Programming} }
\author{ \textbf {John O.R. Aoga \and  Tias Guns \and Pierre
Schaus}}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}

 \textbf {Abstract} Programming (CP) has proven to be an effective platform for
constraint based sequence mining. Previous work has focussed on standard frequent
sequence mining, as well as frequent sequence mining with a maximum ’gap’ between
two matching events in a sequence. The main challenge in the latter is that this cons-
traint can not be imposed independently of the omnipresent frequency constraint.
Indeed, the gap constraint changes whether a subsequence is included in a sequence,
and hence its frequency. In this work, we go beyond that and investigate the in-
tegration of timed events and constraining the minimum/maximum gap as well as
minimum/maximum span. The latter constrains the allowed time between the first
and last matching event of a pattern. We show how the three are interrelated, and
what the required changes to the frequency constraint are. Key in our approach is
the concept of an extension window defined by gap/span and we develop techniques
to avoid scanning the sequences needlessly, as well as using a backtracking-aware
data structure. Experiments demonstrate that the proposed approach outperforms
both specialized and CP-based approaches in almost all cases and that the advantage
increases as the minimum frequency threshold decreases. \\
\\ \textbf {Keywords} Data mining · Sequential pattern mining · Constraint programming ·
Global constraint · Gap constraint · Span constraint · Time constraint
\institute{J.B. Doe
\at Doe Institute, 281 Prime Street, Daisy Town, NA 02467,
USA\\Tel.: +127-47-678901, Fax: +127-47-678907
\and
J.B. Doe \and S.Q. Public
\at Public-Enterprises
\and
J.A. Smith
\at Smith University,\\\email{smith@smith.edu}
}
\end{abstract}

\section*{1 Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Also for this class (`svjour3`) I'm suppose to see the address of authors I put into `\institute` at the end of Abstract but nothing.

Help me.

Comment: You can't use `\textbf{` in `\author` for all of the author names, since author names are typeset in a tabular environment, where `\and` switches to the next cell. With `\textbf{`, you start the bold font in one table cell, but you can't continue to next cell without closing it, i.e. `}`. Either use `\textbf` for each of the author names or remove it completely from `\author` (and `\title`) and say `\begingroup\bfseries\maketitle\endgroup`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE by the way ;-)

Comment: I will remove it. The class `svjour3` put the authors names in bold automatically

Comment: Not related to the problem, but do you really _need_ all those packages? It's hard to think of a reason to load `url` when you also load `hyperref`, for example. Also, `lipsum` isn't usually needed in real documents. At the very least I would get rid of all the duplicates: `amsmath`, `amsfonts`, `amssymb`, `listings` (loaded 3 times), `booktabs`, `graphicx`, `caption` & `xcolor`.

Comment: @morten: I tested with `book` instead of `svjour3` since that class is not installed on my machine

Comment: @lan Thompson the list of package was give to help me to work. So I think I will probably use all it

Comment: @morten --- Loading unnecessary packages won't help you in any way, and may cause problems, especially if you are a beginner.

Comment: @morten you should not use more packages than you really need. This tends to be a big problem for beginners because they just copy stuff without thinking what the purpose of all this is. And then they get incompatibilities and don't know which packages are causing this. In short: It tends to create more problems than it solves. Just don't use all those packages you don't use.

Comment: Is `svjour3` a custom package?  I don't know that we can do much to help you in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I've found. I just have to use `\Institute{}` before `\begin{document}`

like that

```
\institute{J.O.R Aoga
\at Institute of Information and Communication Technologies, Electronics and Applied Mathma-
tics (ICTEAM), UCLouvain, Belgium
Ecole Doctorale Science de l’Ingénieur (ED-SDI), Université d’Abomey-Calavi (UAC), Bénin\\Orcid Id: 0000-0002-7213-146X 
\\\email{john.aoga@\{uclouvain.be,gmail.com\}}
\and
T. Guns
\at Vrije Universiteit Brussel (VUB), Brussels, Belgium
Katholieke Universiteit Leuven, Belgium 
\\\email{tias.guns@\{vub.ac.be,cs.kuleuven.be\}}
\and
P. Schaus
\at Institute of Information and Communication Technologies, Electronics and Applied Mathma-
tics (ICTEAM), UCLouvain, Belgium
\\\email{pierre.schaus@uclouvain.be}
}
\date{}


\begin{document}
```